# Are free groups residually simple?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-groups, simple-groups

Let $F_k$ be a free group of rank $k\ge2$. Given $g\in F_k$ with $g\neq e$, is there $N \vartriangleleft F_k$ such that $g\notin N$ and $F/N$ is finite simple?

Comment: I expect so but don't have a clean argument yet. If $g \in F_k$ is primitive, we can map it to a generator of whatever finite simple group you'd like. If $g$ is not primitive but has a primitive root, one could map that root to a generator of a sufficiently large cyclic group of prime order, etc etc

Comment: Yes this was proved by Weigel in one of his papers on residual properties of free groups. (Why is there a vote to close?)

Comment: I would think that "residually (finite-)simple" instead means that for any $g\neq e$ there is a homomorphism $f:F\to S$ where $S$ is finite simple and $f(g)\neq e$.  That's much easier to prove, since any finite group easily embeds in an alternating group.

Comment: @EricWofsey How does the fact that every finite group embeds in an alternating group help?

Comment: @DerekHolt: It makes the result follow immediately from the fact that free groups are residually finite, since you can take a finite quotient where $g$ survives and then embed it in an alternating group.

Comment: Oh I see yes, but I the question is asking for a quotient of $F_k$ that is simple. I believe that was the question (of Magnus) answered by Weigel .

Comment: Stronger probabilistic results that use CFSG are proved [here](http://www.math.carleton.ca/~jdixon/Residual.pdf)

Comment: @EricWofsey the ambiguity comes from the fact that "residually P" was originally defined for classes P of groups that are closed under taking subgroups. Now "residually" is sometimes meant in the OP's sense, and sometimes in the weaker sense you're suggesting (but which makes the question not interesting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the simplest approach, but with a strong conclusion: it's been proved on the one hand by Margulis and Soifer in the 80's that, for any $k,d\ge 2$ $F_k$ can be embedded as a Zariski-dense subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$. And on the other hand (earlier) by Weisfeiler that every Zariski-dense subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$ has the property that its image modulo every large enough prime is surjective. Combining, we reach the conclusion that $F_k$ is residually-$P_d$ (with surjective maps), for $P_d$ the class of $ \mathrm{PSL}_d(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ where $p$ ranges among primes (or even among any infinite set of primes).

It sounds to me plausible that $F_k$ is residually-P for any subclass $P$ of the class of nonabelian finite simple groups with unbounded order; I'm not sure what the current state of art is (the above uses results of the 80's but there has been much progress since then).

---

*Edit* After finding Derek's suggested reference:

Then it seems that the first proved case, which is enough to answer the OP's question, was the family $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p)$, $p$ prime: it is due to Peluso,  Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 1966.

Next Katz and W. Magnus (Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 22 (1968), 1-13) proved it for the family of all alternating groups, and also extended Peluso's result.  The case of arbitrary families of alternating groups is due to J. Wiegold (Arch. Math. (Basel) 28 (1977), no. 4, 337–339). Lubotzky (Proc AMS) made the connection to the then recent results of Weisfeiler to considerably enlarge the class of known examples among families of groups of Lie type (which was extended by S. Pride in the 70's).

The general case (arbitrary families of nonabelian finite simple groups) is indeed due to T. Weigel (1992,1993) in papers *Residual properties of free groups, I,II,III* in J. Algebra, Comm. Algebra, Israel J. Math.

Comment: In his papers Weigel proved that $F_2$ is residually-P, where P is any infinite set of finite nonabelian simple groups. The result then follows for $F_k$ because $F_k$ is residually $F_2$.